# Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Geofire` in firebase to get the location of two different users. As long as I have just 1 user it works fine but when there are more than two users online then I get the above error

```
 Future<void> initGeoFireListener() async {
    

    var driverLocation =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("availableDrivers").path;

    try {
      Geofire.initialize(driverLocation).catchError((onError) {
        print("Driver $onError");
      });
      Geofire.queryAtLocation(
              position.latitude, position.longitude, 50)! //10 km
          .listen((map) {
        print("drivers map: $map");
        if (map != null) {
          print("Nearby Drivers: $map");
          var callBack = map['callBack'];

          switch (callBack) {
            case Geofire.onKeyEntered:
              NearByAvailableDrivers nearByAvailableDrivers =
                  NearByAvailableDrivers(
                      map['key'], map['latitude'], map['longitude']);

              GeoFireAssistant.nearByAvailableDriversList
                  .add(nearByAvailableDrivers);

              updateAvailableDriversOnMap();
              // }
              break;

            case Geofire.onKeyExited: //when any driver is offline

              GeoFireAssistant.removeDriverFromList(map['key']);
              updateAvailableDriversOnMap();
              //  } else {
              print("xxxx onKeyExited ${availableDrivers.length}");
              // }
              break;

            case Geofire.onKeyMoved: //as driver position change
              NearByAvailableDrivers nearByAvailableDrivers =
                  NearByAvailableDrivers(
                      map['key'], map['latitude'], map['longitude']);

              GeoFireAssistant.updateDriverNearByLocation(
                  nearByAvailableDrivers);
              updateAvailableDriversOnMap();

              break;

            case Geofire.onGeoQueryReady:
              updateAvailableDriversOnMap();
              // } else {
              print("xxxx onGeoqueryready ${availableDrivers.length}");
              // }

              break;
          }
        } else {
          print("Drivers Null");
        }

        //  setState(() {});
      }).onError((error) {
        print("Drivers error $error");
      });
    } on PlatformException {
      print("Drivers : No platformException response");
    }
  }
```

```
void updateAvailableDriversOnMap() async {
    for (NearByAvailableDrivers driver
        in GeoFireAssistant.nearByAvailableDriversList) {  driverKey = driver.key; } //error triggered here
```

```
class NearByAvailableDrivers {
  String? key;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;

  NearByAvailableDrivers(this.key, this.latitude, this.longitude);
}
```

```
class GeoFireAssistant {
  static List<NearByAvailableDrivers> nearByAvailableDriversList = []; //error

  static void removeDriverFromList(String? key) {
    int index =
        nearByAvailableDriversList.indexWhere((element) => element.key == key);
    nearByAvailableDriversList.removeAt(index);
  }

  static void updateDriverNearByLocation(NearByAvailableDrivers driver) {
    int index = nearByAvailableDriversList
        .indexWhere((element) => element.key == driver.key);
    nearByAvailableDriversList[index].latitude = driver.latitude;
    nearByAvailableDriversList[index].longitude = driver.longitude;
  }
}
```

The error

> 

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'

I do understand I am using `For loop` in `NearByAvailableDrivers` and modifying it at the same time which could be the source of the error but I am unable to fix it.

Comment: It **is** the source of the error. But for some reason, you did not post the code in the loop. So... the only option we have is to tell you to not do it. Don't change the Iterable you are going through. Queue your changes somewhere, iterate over a copy, do *something* with the code you are not showing.

Comment: By the way, you have a `void`/`async` method in your code. That is a bug waiting to happen. Fix that. Every `async` method should return a `Future<>`, otherwise it's just some rogue code you have no control over.

Comment: @nvoigt it was just one line of code, I removed it to make the question clearer.  I have updated it.  the `void/async` is from the plugin example itself. Could you provide some basic code that I could follow?